# how to find all objects (class objects/structs) of a C++ executable

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

Is there a way, maybe using nm, or gdb, that will let me create a list of all the object types that an executable contains?

To clarify, I have the source code. I need a method for figuring out all the class/struct sizes that are used at runtime. So this is probably a two part problem:

1. create a list of all classes/structs
2. use sizeof() on each of the items on the list, in gdb.

Comment: unless it was linked with symbol information for the class constructors, this is pretty much impossible to get correct

Comment: `nm -C exe_name` will list all symbols in demangled form, assuming executable was built with debug info

Answer (score 9):

"Types" aren't a property of machine code. They're a property of a high-level, abstract *language*, which is *compiled* into machine code. Unless the compiler makes specific arrangements for you to recover information about the source program, type information generally doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Compilers usually put code into a fairly rich object format, one that can include lots of debugging information, including everything you need to know about types.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml : DeCompiler for C++

You will usually not get good C++ out of a binary unless you compiled in debugging information. Prepare to spend a lot of manual labor reversing the code.

If you didn't strip the binaries there is some hope as IDA Pro can produce C-alike code for you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get a list of types from gdb.  You just want `info types` and then `ptype` if you want to drill down into the type (limiting it to types matching a string just to keep this small):

```
(gdb) info types Q
All types matching regular expression "Q":

File foo.cpp:
Qq;
(gdb) ptype Qq
type = class Qq {
  private:
    int qx;

  public:
    Qq(int);
    std::__cxx11::string something(std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >);
    int getQ(void);
}
```

And sizeof tells you how big the structure is (of course, it's the structure itself, so this may or may not be all that useful):

```
(gdb) p sizeof(Qq)
$1 = 4
(gdb)
```

You'll probably want to run gdb in a script and parse the output somehow.